# Remove QTextDocument which is inside QTextEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to remove `QTextDocument` which is inside the `QTextEdit` but I am not able to do it. I used `clear()` method of `QTextEdit` but it won't clear the `QTextEdit` area. I also try to overwrite new document on previous by setting overwrite flag of `QTextEdit` but that doesn't work as well.

```
def create_doc(body_text):
    doc = QTextDocument()
    doc.setDocumentMargin(10)

    cursor = QTextCursor(doc)
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Start)

    block_fmt = QTextBlockFormat()
    block_fmt.setBottomMargin(6)
    block_fmt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignJustify)

    para_fmt = QTextCharFormat()
    para_fmt.setFontWeight(QFont.Normal)
    para_fmt.setFontPointSize(12)
    para_fmt.setFontFamilies(["Raleway", "Arial"])

    cursor.insertBlock(block_fmt)
    cursor.insertText(body_text, para_fmt)
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.End)

    return doc


class AppUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(AppUI, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.qTextEditArea.setOverwriteMode(True)
        self.ui.button.clicked.connect(lambda : self.add_text("some text")

    def add_text(self, text):
        self.ui.qTextEditArea.clear()
        document = create_doc(doc)
        self.ui.qTextEditArea.setDocument(document)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = AppUI()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you know how to do it please help. Thanks

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick I have added the example, please check it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QTextEdit Class**

> document : QTextDocument*
>
> This property holds the underlying document of the text editor.
>
> Note: The editor does not take ownership of the document unless it is the document's parent object. The parent object of the provided document remains the owner of the object. If the previously assigned document is a child of the editor then it will be deleted.
>
> Access functions:
>
> QTextDocument *   document() const
>
> void          setDocument(QTextDocument *document)

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from textEditArea import Ui_MainWindow


def create_doc(body_text):
    doc = QTextDocument()
    doc.setDocumentMargin(10)

    cursor = QTextCursor(doc)
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Start)

    block_fmt = QTextBlockFormat()
    block_fmt.setBottomMargin(6)
    block_fmt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignJustify)

    para_fmt = QTextCharFormat()
    para_fmt.setFontWeight(QFont.Normal)
    para_fmt.setFontPointSize(12)
    
    para_fmt.setFontFamilies(["Raleway", "Arial"])  # This function was introduced in Qt 5.13.

    cursor.insertBlock(block_fmt)
    cursor.insertText(body_text, para_fmt)
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.End)

    return doc


class AppUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(AppUI, self).__init__()
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        
#        self.ui.qTextEditArea.setOverwriteMode(True)
        
        self.ui.button.clicked.connect(lambda : self.add_text("some text"))   

    def add_text(self, text):
#        self.ui.qTextEditArea.clear()
#        document = create_doc(doc)                      # ??? (doc)
        document = create_doc(text)                      # +++ text   
        self.ui.qTextEditArea.setDocument(document)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = AppUI()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**textEditArea.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(456, 304)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.qTextEditArea = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.qTextEditArea.setObjectName("qTextEditArea")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.qTextEditArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button.setObjectName("button")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 456, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

[image]